# Is OneTime binding in code different from setting local value directly?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

What is the difference between this **OneTime** binding:

```
//Create the source string
string s = "Hello";

//Create the binding description
Binding b = new Binding("");
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneTime;
b.Source = s;

//Attach the binding to the target
MyText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
```

And this?

```
MyText.Text = s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very much different. By the second method you can change your bound value at any point of time in code. But with one time binding the bound value is evaluated only on app start or data context change.
See OneTime binding description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx).

Comment: But in case of string bindings the bound value is immutable so it happens there's no difference, right?

Comment: Bindings are useful only when used with a property that notifies it's value changes, thus providing an easy mechanism to gel your model with view. As in your case you are using a variable for binding. So even if you change the value of variable it is not going to be reflected in your view element until you notify it. This is true for a string or any other type.

Comment: OK, so we can say there is no difference between the two methods in my question?